# Iterating through 2D arrays adding scores as you go in php

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I am trying to iterate through an array that contains the scores for different players in a round robin competition.  I want to create another array that is basically a ladder listing each individual player and their total score.

My score table looks like this:

```
    id  Home    Home    Away    Away
        _Name   _Score  _Name   _Score
    -----------------------------------
    1   Mark    NULL    Darren  NULL
    2   Andrea  2       Greg    7
    3   Claire  2       Test 6  3
    4   Mark    NULL    Andrea  NULL
    5   Claire  NULL    Darren  NULL
    6   Test 6  NULL    Greg    NULL
    7   Mark    NULL    Claire  NULL
    8   Test 6  NULL    Andrea  NULL
    9   Greg    NULL    Darren  NULL
    10  Mark    NULL    Test 6  NULL
    11  Greg    NULL    Claire  NULL
    12  Darren  NULL    Andrea  NULL
    13  Mark    NULL    Greg    NULL
    14  Darren  NULL    Test 6  NULL
    15  Andrea  NULL    Claire  NULL
```

I can get this nicely into a 15 x 5 array called $rows.  I can also get all the distinct player names into a nice 6 x 1 array called $names.  I want to iterate through $names adding the value of the home score or away score whenever the home or away player is equal to the names value, thus calculating their total score.

my code looks like this:

```
<?php 
for ($i=0; $i<count($names); $i++) {
    print($names[$i]);
    echo " - ";
    $score = 0;
    for ($j=0;$j<count($rows);$j++) {
        if ($rows[$j][1] = $names[$i]) {
            $score = $score + $rows[$j][2];
        }
        if ($rows[$j][3] = $names[$i]) {
            $score = $score + $rows[$j][4];
        }

    }
    print($score);

    echo "<br><br>";
}
?>
```

Instead of returning Andrea and Claire on 2, Greg on 7, Test 6 on 3 and everyone else on 0 I get the following:

```
    Mark - 14

    Andrea - 14

    Claire - 14

    Darren - 14

    Greg - 14

    Test 6 - 14
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `==` instead of `=` for equality checking. You should set your error reporting to `E_ALL | E_NOTICE` so that even these errors will be reported as a notice. While it is valid code, it is probably not what you intended to do.

Comment: Thanks very much -  I'll have to look into the error reporting as this could have saved me hours.  Very frustrating.  I wish I had come here when I first ran into the problem. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use double "=" when comparing two values. if you use just one it always returns true

```
    if ($rows[$j][1] == $names[$i]) {
        $score = $score + $rows[$j][2];
    }
    if ($rows[$j][3] == $names[$i]) {
        $score = $score + $rows[$j][4];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much - This does it very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($rows[$j][1] = $names[$i])
```

You have to use == for the check

```
$score = $score + $rows[$j][2];
```

That would be:

```
$score += $rows[$j][2];
```